# Filter list according to Current date android

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a `ArrayList<CustomObject>` which contains some entries. Each entry has a Date associated with it. Currently, the date is stored as a String. eg `"2014-09-23T12:45:00"`

I want to filter the list to get a refined list containing the entries only done today.

Iam using `Pattern` to achieve this. But currently Iam receiving a null List after filtering.

Here is my code:--

```
public class ArticleFilter implements Predicate<StatusResponse>
{
    private final Pattern pattern;

    public ArticleFilter(final String regex)
    {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean apply(final StatusResponse input)
    {
        String dateString =  input.getStartTime();

        dateString =  dateString.split("T")[0]; // Getting date only
        return pattern.matcher(dateString).find();
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance(); //Get the current date
            SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); //format it as per your requirement
            String dateNow = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime());
            ArrayList<StatusResponse> filteredResultList = Lists.newArrayList(Collections2.filter(resultList, new ArticleFilter(dateNow)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here lies in your formatter.

You have specified a SimpleDateFormat of "yyyy/MM/dd", but you tell us that your date is stored as a string in the format "2014-09-23T12:45:00". You need to change your SimpleDateFormat to match the format of the date string in your StatusResponse class.

Change it to be

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

That fixes the imediate problem. However, could I recommend that you don't deal with string representations of dates at all, and instead change your code to deal directly with Calendar only?

For instance, have your `StatusResponse.getStartTime` method return a `Calendar` representing the start time, have your `ArticleFilter` constructor take a `Calendar` representing the day to filter on, and have your `apply` method check that both calendars return the same value for `get(Calendar.YEAR)` and for `get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)`